# How to place msCardView in ScrollView

Tags: android, basic4android

I'm trying to use CardView buttons in ScrollView by this code but It doesn't work.I define a sub to place My MsCardView to ScrollView one by one. I'm new in Basic4Android and I can't understand where is the problem!  I will be appreciate if you help me understand how I can fix it!
    :`

```
Sub Globals
 Dim ScrollView1 As ScrollView
End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)

ScrollView1.Initialize("ScrollView1")
ScrollView1.Color=0xFFEEEEEE


Activity.AddView(ScrollView1,0,100%y,100%x,100%y-100dip)

MainItems

End Sub


Sub MainItems

 Dim a1 As MSCardView
 a1.Initialize("a1")
 ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(a1,50%x-100dip,20dip,200dip,80dip)


 Dim aLbl As Label
 aLbl.Initialize("aLbl")
 aLbl.Text="Season1"
 aLbl.TextSize=20
 aLbl.Gravity=Gravity.CENTER
 aLbl.Typeface=Typeface.LoadFromAssets("myandroid.ttf")
 aLbl.TextColor=Colors.RGB(50,50,50)
 a1.Panel.AddView(aLbl,50dip,20dip,100dip,40dip)


Dim a2 As MSCardView
a2.Initialize("a2")
ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(a2,50%x-100dip,20dip,200dip,80dip)


Dim aLb2 As Label
aLb2.Initialize("aLb2")
aLb2.Text="Season2"
aLb2.TextSize=20
aLb2.Gravity=Gravity.CENTER
aLb2.Typeface=Typeface.LoadFromAssets("myandroid.ttf")
aLb2.TextColor=Colors.RGB(50,50,50)
a2.Panel.AddView(aLb2,50dip,20dip,100dip,40dip)


Dim a3 As MSCardView
a3.Initialize("a3")
ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(a3,50%x-100dip,20dip,200dip,80dip)


Dim aLb3 As Label
aLb3.Initialize("aLb3")
aLb3.Text="Season3"
aLb3.TextSize=20
aLb3.Gravity=Gravity.CENTER
aLb3.Typeface=Typeface.LoadFromAssets("myandroid.ttf")
aLb3.TextColor=Colors.RGB(50,50,50)
a3.Panel.AddView(aLb3,50dip,20dip,100dip,40dip)

.
.
.
End Sub
```

`

Comment: Why do you need Basic4Android? It is starving and not liveable branch. The time of vb has gone away.

Comment: I think I can contact with it better than other languages. However I am an old man too :) What is your suggest instead it? I found java and Eclips a little more tricky for me! I just want to be familiar with mobile programming!

Comment: Yes, Java but NO eclipse. Use Android Studio

Comment: Thank you Beloo may be one day I'd switch to JAVA But The problem is still remained!

Comment: if u find a way please tell me how can i implement the cardView on ULV

Answer (score 0):

add this code after #Region  Project Attributes  and see if this works

```
#AditionalRes : E:\Barname\Basic4android\Compatible B4A Collection\SDK\extras\android\support\v7\cardview
```

(you should address your own Android Support file in your SDK)

(If you don't have **Android Support** file in your SDK folder, then you must download it by searching it at google)